# Modelagem de Dados (Sistema escala de revezamento)

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, modelo-relacional

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para escala de revezamento.

Pensem como uma especie de calendário, onde um dia possui vários turnos, turno possui várias posições, e funcionário é escalado para a posição.

Funcionário pode estar escalado ou de folga, se estiver escalado, preciso saber em qual dia, qual turno e qual posição. 
Já modelei as entidades fortes. Porém estou tendo dificuldades para modelar os relacionamentos.

Pensei em uma entidade "escala", onde haveria a intersecção de dia, turno, posição e funcionário. No entanto encontrei alguns problemas, como por exemplo, consigo escalar o mesmo funcionário para o mesmo turno e posição no mesmo dia, ou consigo escalar dois funcionários para a mesma posição no mesmo turno e mesmo dia.

Deixo em anexo um esboço do modelo conceitual.
obs: Sei que pelas regras, as relações N:M geram uma entidade associativa.
No entanto não entendo como essas entidades se relacionariam com as demais.

Se tiver alguém que conheça bastante de modelagem e estiver disposto a ajudar agradeço.

[image: DER]

Segue o script do sqlverver:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ABSENCE (
  idABSENCE INTEGER CHECK (idABSENCE > 0) NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  NICKNAME_ABS VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  REASON_ABS VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(idABSENCE)
);

CREATE TABLE DESK (
  idDESK INTEGER CHECK (idDESK > 0) NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  TYPE_DESK_idTYPE_DESK INTEGER CHECK (TYPE_DESK_idTYPE_DESK > 0) NOT NULL,
  NICKNAME_DES VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPTION_DES VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(idDESK)
);

CREATE INDEX FK_TYP_DESK ON DESK(TYPE_DESK_idTYPE_DESK);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  idEMPLOYEE INTEGER CHECK (idEMPLOYEE > 0) NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  SHIFT_idSHIFT INTEGER CHECK (SHIFT_idSHIFT > 0) NOT NULL,
  LICENCE_idLICENCE INTEGER CHECK (LICENCE_idLICENCE > 0) NOT NULL,
  TEAM_idTEAM INTEGER CHECK (TEAM_idTEAM > 0) NOT NULL,
  NAME_EMP VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  LASTNAME_EMP VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  NICKNAME_EMP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  TRIGRAM_EMP VARCHAR(3) NULL,
  USER_EMAIL VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  USER_PASSWORD VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  POST_EMP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(idEMPLOYEE)
);

CREATE INDEX FK_TEA ON EMPLOYEE(TEAM_idTEAM);
CREATE INDEX FK_LIC ON EMPLOYEE(LICENCE_idLICENCE);
CREATE INDEX FK_PRIM_SHI ON EMPLOYEE(SHIFT_idSHIFT);
CREATE INDEX FK_SEC_SHI ON EMPLOYEE(SHIFT_idSHIFT);

CREATE TABLE EQUIPMENT (
  idEQUIPMENT INTEGER CHECK (idEQUIPMENT > 0) NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  BRAND_EQU VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  MODEL_EQU VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(idEQUIPMENT)
);

CREATE TABLE LICENCE (
  idLICENCE INTEGER CHECK (idLICENCE > 0) NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  DATEOFISSUE_LIC DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL,
  VALIDTO_LIC DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(idLICENCE)
);

CREATE TABLE LIC_EQU (
  LICENCE_idLICENCE INTEGER CHECK (LICENCE_idLICENCE > 0) NOT NULL,
  EQUIPMENT_idEQUIPMENT INTEGER CHECK (EQUIPMENT_idEQUIPMENT > 0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(LICENCE_idLICENCE, EQUIPMENT_idEQUIPMENT)
);

CREATE INDEX FK_LIC ON LIC_EQU(LICENCE_idLICENCE);
CREATE INDEX FK_EQU ON LIC_EQU(EQUIPMENT_idEQUIPMENT);

CREATE TABLE SCHEDULE (
  idSCHEDULE INTEGER CHECK (idSCHEDULE > 0) NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  SHIFT_idSHIFT INTEGER CHECK (SHIFT_idSHIFT > 0) NOT NULL,
  DESK_idDESK INTEGER CHECK (DESK_idDESK > 0) NOT NULL,
  ABSENCE_idABSENCE INTEGER CHECK (ABSENCE_idABSENCE > 0) NULL,
  EMPLOYEE_idEMPLOYEE INTEGER CHECK (EMPLOYEE_idEMPLOYEE > 0) NULL,
  DATE_EXEC DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL,
  SCH_STATUS INTEGER CHECK (SCH_STATUS > 0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(idSCHEDULE)
);

CREATE INDEX FK_EMP ON SCHEDULE(EMPLOYEE_idEMPLOYEE);
CREATE INDEX FK_ABS ON SCHEDULE(ABSENCE_idABSENCE);
CREATE INDEX FK_DESK ON SCHEDULE(DESK_idDESK);
CREATE INDEX FK_SHI ON SCHEDULE(SHIFT_idSHIFT);

CREATE TABLE SHIFT (
  idSHIFT INTEGER CHECK (idSHIFT > 0) NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  NICKNAME_SHI VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  START_SHI DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL,
  FINISH_SHI DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(idSHIFT)
);

CREATE TABLE TEAM (
  idTEAM INTEGER CHECK (idTEAM > 0) NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  NAME_TEA VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(idTEAM)
);

CREATE TABLE TYPE_DESK (
  idTYPE_DESK INTEGER CHECK (idTYPE_DESK > 0) NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  NAME_TYP_DES VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(idTYPE_DESK)
);
```

Já pesquisei na literatura, porém as relações ternárias que encontro não me ajudaram muito, então gostaria de saber como identifico as possíveis relações ternárias nesse diagrama.

Comment: Olá @Isaias Nori seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! A SO é uma comunidade de programação, seja mais específico na sua pergunta, mostre o que tentou e nos dê um exemplo reprodutível do seu código para podermos ajudá-lo.